# How to convert timestamp from MySQL table to human readable form

Tags: mysql

Any idea how to format a timestamp from a MySQL table inside a query to a human readable form?

Example:

```
{ts '1978-01-16 00:00:00'}
```

Needed output:

```
16-01-1978
```

I have tried:

```
select DATE_FORMAT(BIRTHDAY, '%d-%m-%Y') FROM cs_user
```

with no success:

```
[Table (rows 10 columns DATE_FORMAT(BIRTHDAY, '%D-%M-%Y')): [DATE_FORMAT(BIRTHDAY, '%D-%M-%Y'): coldfusion.sql.QueryColumn@1077e6ed] ] is not indexable by DATE_FORMAT(BIRTHDAY
```

My `BIRTHDAY` column is created as `date` in the MySQL table.

Comment: check out mysql `date_format()` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after DATE_FORMAT in a bracket first parameter will be column of the table, then the date format,

Try this

```
select DATE_FORMAT(date, '%d-%m-%Y') as BIRTHDATE FROM cs_user
```

find the below link for all the date format which mysql supports.

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_format.asp

Answer (score 2):

Take the alias name for the field and try it.

```
select DATE_FORMAT(BIRTHDAY, '%d-%m-%Y') as some_alias_name FROM cs_user
```

check, [this for an example related to this.](http://www.mccran.co.uk/index.cfm/2010/3/5/Returning-values-from-mySQL-in-a-select-query-as-YesNo-rather-than-10)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT( FROM_UNIXTIME( table.column ) , '%d - %m - %Y' ) FROM table
```

Comment: Unfortunately getting the same error `.. is not indexable by DATE_FORMAT( FROM_UNIXTIME( BIRTHDAY )`